# Why does the user have to enter their correct credentials two times?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

```
public ActionResult Login(CredentialsModel model)
{
    authenticator.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password);

    if (authenticator.Authenticated)
    {
        return Redirect();
    }
}

...

public class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    public bool Authenticated
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; }
    }

    public void Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        var authenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
        if (authenticated)
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

When the aforementioned action method supplies some valid credentials to the `Authenticate` method, the `Authenticated` property returns false which is clearly wrong.

When the action method supplies some credentials for a *second* time, the `Authenticated` property returns true.

I suspect this has something to with the fact that context is not updated immediately.  I actually managed to resolve this bug by using the immediate return value of `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` in the action method but I want to know *why* this bug occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the HTTP context sent with/of first call user is **not** authenticated (but it'll correctly be after that, for subsequent calls). After this line:

```
var authenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
```

You may see that `authenticated != Authenticated`. Why? From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx):

> [HttpContext] Encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.

It means that it works on **request** (your input) not on **response** or future state (your output). If you perform `SignOut()` inside your controller's method you'll also see that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still `true`.

What you can do is to add a boolean return value for `Authenticate()`:

```
public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    var authenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
    if (authenticated)
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);

    return authenticated:
}
```

Changing then code in controller to:

```
if (authenticator.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password))
{
    return Redirect();
}
```

Comment: This answer is not all that helpful to me sorry. Please elaborate on the first paragraph. The code samples are also not helpful to me as I have already solved the problem like I mentioned in the question :c

Comment: I updated answer with some code. In short: HttpContext refers to an HTTP **request**. In that context user WAS not authenticated (and HttpContext won't change while you process his request because you're working on response).

Comment: There we go mate. Spot on. Thanks.